# Determine postgres numeric max min values

Tags: postgresql

In one of my PostgreSQL table there is an attribute result with datatype Numeric(20,10).

One of its input value can be +/- infinity.

I want to know with the length (20,10) what are the maximum & minimum values.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL

Comment: @CraigRinger, thanks. What I understood from this is max value can be of 10^10. i.e. 9999999999.9999999999

Comment: `((10^20)-1)/(10^10)` actually. Because of the fractional part.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For a numeric of `numeric(precision, scale)`, the limit values are:

```
+- ((10^precision)-1)/(10^scale)
```

so for `numeric(20,10)` that'd be `((10^20)-1)/(10^10)` or `9999999999.9999999999` .

[Details in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL).

Answer (score 0):

For long decimals, you might run into precision errors in languages like JavaScript. So you can do something like this.

```js
const calcluateDecimalMax = (x: number, y: number): string => {
    const leftCount = x - y
    const rightCount = y
    const leftString = "9".repeat(leftCount)
    const rightString = "9".repeat(rightCount)
    return `${leftString}.${rightString}`
}

console.log(calcluateDecimalMax(25, 9)) // "9999999999999999.999999999"
```