# Is there data type in Postgresql for big number and long decimal?

Tags: postgresql

I have a project which is need big number and long decimal, for example 123456789,1234567891 (at least 10 digit behind comma).

I already tried numeric(20,10) it gave me only 6 behind comma

edit:
i read this [Determine postgres numeric max min values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26396856/determine-postgres-numeric-max-min-values) and using numeric(20,10) but it just give me 6 behind comma

edit:
it look like navicat have a bug or something, i'm using dbeaver and i can store more than 6 digit behind comma.

thank you

Comment: have you considered using Postgres documentation? e.g. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/datatype.html

Comment: @PaulMaxwell hi, i already read that. maybe I'm missing something, can you give me a clue? thanks for reply

Comment: perhaps you could re-consider the level of detail in your question, it is a bit vague. Why have numeric not worked? Why for example would bigint not work for you? it is much larger than +/-123456789 and that is apparent with even just a casual reading of the data type page.

Comment: try this table: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/datatype-numeric.html

Comment: "using numeric(20,10) ... just give me 6 behind comma" -- `numeric(20, 10)` can hold a number with 20 digits, 10 of them after `.`. Have a look [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=86599f707b16781a20c21403e0584418). Maybe you actually have a client issue, i.e. it is the client that cannot or just for any reason doesn't display more digits.

Comment: @stickybit thank you! it is navicat issue, its okay in dbeaver

Answer (score 1):

The 6 digits after the comma make me guess that you cast to `double precision` (`float8`) first. (Or something in your food-chain is dumb enough to do that.) See:

```sql
test=> SELECT '123456789.1234567891'::float::numeric(20,10);
       numeric        
----------------------
 123456789.1234570000
(1 row)

test=> SELECT '123456789.1234567891'::numeric(20,10);
       numeric        
----------------------
 123456789.1234567891
(1 row)
```